# FluidTYPO3 vhs ViewHelper for SVG Images?

Tags: svg, typo3, fluid, flux, viewhelper

I use TYPO3 CMS 6.2.14, `vhs 2.3.3`, `Flux 7.2.1` and `FluidContent 4.3.1` - my TYPO3 Editor need the opportunity to upload SVG-Images via `vhs`-ViewHelper. I've made a new [FluidTYPO3](https://fluidtypo3.org/) Content Element (FCE), but there's no SVG Image visible in frontend.  Mmhh?

[image: Allow also SVG to Upload]

Flux-FlexForm

```
<flux:field.file name="imgIcon" allowed="jpg,gif,png,jpeg,svg" uploadFolder="uploads/tx_myext" minItems="0" maxItems="1" size="1" />
...
 <v:media.image src="uploads/tx_myext/{imgIcon}" alt="Icon" />
```

Output

```
<div class="small-2 columns">
  <img alt="Icon" src="" width="" height="">
</div>
```

[image: no SVG image availible]

Also I use the htaccess entry, but there is no success. Where's my fault? Do I need `height`and `width`for this ViewHelper? Aren't vectors availible in `vhs`?

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    ...
    AddType image/svg+xml                   svg svgz
    AddEncoding gzip                        svgz
    ...
</Ifmodule>
```

EDIT: I also tried the Fluid ViewHelper, but the SVG Image has `height/width = 0`:

```
<f:image src="uploads/tx_myext/{imgIcon}" width="50" height="50" class="xy" alt="Icon" />
```

EDIT 2: The ImagePath is correct. At Developer Tools I "see" the Image ..
[image: image path correct]

EDIT 3: Oh, I see at my Filemanager (FAL) `0x0 pixels` ..
[image]

Comment: Is the path to the file correct? Maybe the location ``uploads/tx_myext`` is stored in the database und must not be set in the viewhelper. Debug the variables using ``<f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>`` somewhere in the template, it displays all available variables and their values.

Comment: Hi merec, the path is correct. look at my EDIT 2 ...

Comment: But the path to the image in the output is now shown. There is a bug with svgs, see https://forge.typo3.org/issues/66445

Comment: Oh, yes .. I see it at `typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Type/File/FileInfo.php` :: L31 `// @todo will be implemented in issue #60019` Hope that solve my problem ...

Comment: Oha .. I see the TagretVersion at your Fourge-Link is TYPO3 CMS 7. I'm using TYPO3 6.2.14. Do I need an update from 6.2 to 7.x to solve the Problem? Or maybe I'll use my SVG-Images as a `backgeound-image`?!

Comment: I would use ``<img src="{f:uri.image(src: 'uploads/tx_myext/{imgIcon}')}">`` instead of ``<f:image``, that should work.

Comment: Yeah, that works. Thank you. I've tried it with the `vhs`and `fluid`ViewHelper, but not with the inline-notation. You can also use CSS to give the SVG Image a height and width. This also works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [merec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2110794/merec).

Use SVG Images / TYPO3 6.2 with FluidTYPO3

Answer: Use

```
<img src="{f:uri.image(src: 'uploads/tx_myext/{imgIcon}')}">
```

instead of

```
<v:media.image src="uploads/tx_myext/{imgIcon}" alt="Icon" />
// OR
<f:image src="uploads/tx_myext/{imgIcon}" width="50" height="50" class="xy" alt="Icon" />
```

Comment: its better practice to used media exist or not? You can check here : https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/1.3.1/Media/ExistsViewHelper.html