# TYPO3 DCE (Fluid): How to generate an SVG Object instead of an image tag?

Tags: html, svg, typo3, fluid, tx-dce

Our TYPO3 users (editors) need to exchange / update SVG files to the TYPO3 website. The svg files are clickable, hence the `<img>` html tag does not work for them. We decided in favour of the `<object>` tag, with `<img>` fallback ([Do I use <img>, <object>, or <embed> for SVG files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476526/do-i-use-img-object-or-embed-for-svg-files)).

The Fluid code for the fronted is easy for generating normal img tags:

```
<f:layout name="Default" />
<f:section name="main">
 <div class="container">
  <f:for each="{dce:fal(field:'image1', contentObject:contentObject)}" as="fileReference" iteration="iterator">
   <f:if condition="{iterator.isFirst}">
    <f:image src="{fileReference.uid}" alt="" treatIdAsReference="1" />
   </f:if>
  </f:for>
 </div>
</f:section>
```

However, according to [FluidTYPO3 vhs ViewHelper for SVG Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32228003/fluidtypo3-vhs-viewhelper-for-svg-images), I might be able to use fluid code like this:

```
<img src="{f:uri.image(src: 'uploads/tx_myext/{imgIcon}')}">
```

which, adapted to object, would be:

```
<object data="{f:uri.image(src: 'xxx')}" type="image/svg+xml">
  <img src="{f:uri.image(src: 'xxx')}">
</object>
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea what to provide as src. `{fileReference.uid}` only inserts the unique id of the file (a number).

How can I convert the file id to the relative or absolute URI of the picture?

Comment: What does this mean? "The svg files are clickable, hence the html tag does not work for them."

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I forgot to `` markup html tags, so these were invisible. I meant the html tag `<img>` does not work for them. Edited question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the viewhelper attribute **treatIdAsReference** is what you are looking for.
f:image  as well as f:uri:image  can handle Files and FileReferences.

It looks like you have a FileReference, so you should add the attribute with value 1
Here is an example with inline notation:

```
{f:uri.image(src: '{fileReference.uid}', treatIdAsReference:'1')}
```

The result of this is the path to your file, it can be used in regular HTML-Tags.